# Library not properly importing java

Tags: java, eclipse, jsoup, noclassdeffounderror

Using JSoup for html scraping, I'm attempting to compile my jarfile so that I may run this off Eclipse. As seen here: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUgu3.jpg), my jsoup jarfile is added to the external libraries. However, upon running the program I get a NoClassDefFoundError. This is insinuative that it's not finding the classfiles, so I decompiled and double-checked: The class files were within the imported jar. The manifest file is correct too.

I'm running: Eclipse: Build id: 20110916-0149, Java 7 update 5 (64 bit), and jsoup 1.6.3,

And I am not compiling using Maven.

Comment: I'm running it using a bat file, with my network card it's not possible to run this type of application in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You state:

> The manifest file is correct too.

But are you sure? What in fact does your jar file's manifest look like? It should look something like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: yourMainClassPackage.YourMainClass
Class-Path: jsoup-1.6.3.jar
```

And are you sure that your jsoup jar file is located in the correct location relative to its path specification in the manifest?

Comment: My manifest looks exactly like that (with the Main-Class different, ofc). Everything is correct as far as I can see in the Manifest file

Comment: @AmberKiernan: but where is the jsoup jar file relative to your created jar file?

Comment: Located in the same folder as the jarfile

Comment: @AmberKiernan: Is the bat file located in the same folder as well?

Comment: Yup, all the resources are in the same directory

Comment: @AmberKiernan: then I'm completely flummoxed and perplexed. Sorry.

Comment: As a small update, it works perfectly fine running NetBeans, but I'd still like to make it work with Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

The class cannot be found because:

Your Class-Path declaration is `Class-Path: jsoup-1.6.3.jar`, however from your screenshot, the `jsoup-1.6.3.jar` is in `c:\Users\Amber\Desktop\New Folder`, so unless you're running your JAR file from the same folder, it will not be found.

Solutions:

1. Run your JAR from `c:\Users\Amber\Desktop\New Folder`
2. -or- Copy `jsoup-1.6.3.jar` to the same folder as your JAR
3. -or- Have a common folder for all your libs (like c:\java\libs) and include this folder in the CLASSPATH system environment variable